# How to POST data as JSON in the following format

Tags: php, json, post

I need to send POST data in the following format.

```
{
  "buys": [
    {
      "productId": "1ae9ac1a37934fde92d7545cd6c93c13",
      "amount": 200.00
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, my PHP script that the form submits to is.

```
<?php
$productId = $_POST['productId'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$type = $_POST['name'];

//API Url
$url = 'https://********.com/post_test.php';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'type' => $type,
    'productId' => $productId,
    'amount' => $amount
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

This is the output after submitting to form on the frontend, which isn't correct. I thought it would redirect to the inputted URL but I assume it's not meant to and it only posts? (as I typed that I to wondered if the output I'm seeing is from the webpage that I am linking at the top of the script, as that page simply echos the JSON as a string).

```
{"type":"buys","productId":"2ed913357e8842e9a38f0a16eb9703a9","amount":"45866"}
```

I really don't have any idea what to do next, or what to google to find a tutorial.

Some more details, I have a form that submits to the PHP script above. The variable $name is the "buys" in the requested format, the other variables are self-explanatory.

I'm sure there is just a way I need to format the JSON using my variables but I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: `print_r(json_decode(Your_json_string, true));` will show you array you need

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$jsonData`:

```php
$jsonData = array(
    'type' => $type,
    'productId' => $productId,
    'amount' => $amount
);
```

As follows:

```php
$jsonData = array();
$jsonData[ $type ] = array();
$jsonData[ $type ][] = array(
    'productId' => $productId,
    'amount' => $amount
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I originally jumped the gun on the answer I marked as correct. This is what i need as it has the []

Answer (score 1):

your json data should be like this

```php
$jsonData = array(
    $type => array(
       'productId' => $productId,
       'amount' => $amount
    )
);
```

**output :**

> {"busy":{"productId":"1ae9ac1a37934fde92d7545cd6c93c13","amount":"200.00"}}

Answer (score 1):

So you want buys to be an array :

```
//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    $type =>
    array(
        'productId' => $productId,
        'amount' => $amount
    )
);
```

The output will be `{"bugs":{"productId":"productId","amount":"amount"}}`

Comment: Thank you, makes so much sense now I've been shown. Learning every day

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
   $jsonData['buys'][] = array(
         'productId' => $productId,
        'amount' => $amount
    );
```